# Qt's QRegExp and Method Order

Tags: regex, qt

I have two QRegExp objects that I use to search for the start and finish of some text. My code looks something like:

```
// strText defined earlier
QRegExp start(...);
QRegExp end(...);

int iStart = start.indexIn(strText);
int iEnd = end.indexIn(strText, iStart) + end.matchedLength();
```

I have two questions regarding this code:

(1) Assume that the text each regex is looking for is found. Calling the above code invokes the following error at runtime:

> Unhandled exception at 0x66b48b3f in TerminalWindow.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

I get the same error if I change the code around to read:

```
int iStart = start.indexIn(strText);
int iTemp = end.matchedLength();
int iEnd = start.indexIn(strText, iStart) + iTemp;
```

The error in this second code snippet makes sense to me since internally matchedLength() is probably running against an object that has yet to be allocated. However, I do not understand why I'm getting the same error from the first code snippet too. With all other things being equal isn't the order of operations from left to right? If I change the code to the following, then I get the results I expect:

```
// strText defined earlier
QRegExp start(...);
QRegExp end(...);

int iStart = start.indexIn(strText);
int iEnd = end.indexIn(strText, iStart);
iEnd += end.matchedLength();
```

(2) If strText from my examples looks something like:

```
<start>
  stackoverflow is awesome!
</start>
<start>
  I like cake!
</start>
<start>
  Girls are pretty!
</start>
```

How can I write a Qt RegExp that will capture the contents of each start element? Something like:

```
QRegExp reg("<start>(.*?)</start>");
```

Never works for me even though it seems like it should work with POSIX regex (which is what I believe Qt implements). (Note: I'm aware that the ideal way to do this would be with an XML/HTML parser (I'm actually parsing HTML) but I'm interested in a regular expression solution right now).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`<` and `>` need to be escaped. Try:

```
QRegExp reg("\<start\>(.*?)\</start\>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem with your first code snippet. It works fine for me on my Ubuntu box.

As far as your regex is concerned there are a couple of problems. First, you are using the `?` in order to do your regex non-greedy, but it doesn't work with `Qt`. Instead you have to call the `QRegExp.setMinimal(bool)` method. Quoting the [QRegExp reference docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qregexp.html#notes-for-perl-users):

> Non-greedy matching cannot be applied to individual quantifiers, but
>   can be applied to all the quantifiers in the pattern

If your string is something like:

```
'<root>\n<start>\nSo is awesome!\n</start>\n<start>\nI like cake!\n</start>\n</root>'
```

then the following regex will work fine (PyQt version tested on my Ubuntu box):

```
QRegExp rx("<start>\n(.*)\n</start>");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

Now all you have to do is loop as follows (not completely sure of it, I'm not a C++ guy):

```
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;  
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

The second problem I see is that, as you say in the question, a regex shouldn't be used for this task. `Qt` provides the `QtXml` module that contains lots of classes for manipulating XML data.

In your case you one possibility is to use the `QDomDocument` class. The following PyQt code shows how to do it:

```
from PyQt4.QtXml import QDomDocument

mydata = "<root><start>\nSo is awesome!\n</start>\n<start>\nI like cake!\n</start><start>\nI like girls!\n</start></root>"
document = QDomDocument()
document.setContent(mydata)
root = document.documentElement()
element = root.firstChildElement("start")
while (not element.isNull()):
    value = element.firstChild().nodeValue()
    element = element.nextSiblingElement("start")
    print value
```

I'm sure you can convert it to `Qt` code quite easily if you try it.

Comment: I've received no feedback at all about the answer. Can you tell me if it was useful? If it wasn't maybe I can improve it.